# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," AND SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

*app.js*

```js
let ids = [1, 2, 3];

let obj = {};

for (let i in ids) {
  obj = { ...obj, ids[i]: "" };   
}

console.log(obj);
```

While executing the above code, I get the below error.

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  4 |
  5 | for (let i in ids) {
> 6 |   obj = { ...obj, ids[i]: "" };  
    |                      ^
  7 | }
  8 |
  9 | console.log(obj);eslint
```

I get this error, when I hover the mouse above the line `obj = { ...obj, ids[i]: "" };` in my VS Code.

When I run the code using node, i.e on `node app.js`. I get the following error in my terminal :

```
obj = { ...obj, ids[i]: "" };  
                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

What am I doing wrong? I expect the value of `obj` at the end to be `{1 : "", 2 : "", 3: ""}`

Comment: What do you want `obj` to end up looking like?

Comment: I expect the value of obj at the end to be {1 : "", 2 : "", 3: ""}. This is mentioned in the question too, towards the end.

Comment: Don't use `for`/`in` on arrays. It's meant for objects. Use [`for`/`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or one of the other methods intended for iterating over arrays.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to do this? An array is technically already an object of the shape you're trying to achieve (just with a few additional properties). You can clone your array using `const newArr = [...ids];` which might be a better option for you. If you really need an object, one quick option could be to use `const obj = Object.assign({}, ids);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several solutions.

1. Wrap it around a bracket:

```js
for (let i in ids) {
  obj = { ...obj, [ids[i]]: "" }; // Brackets make it act as a key name instead of something else
}
```

2. The simple and easy way:

```js
for (let i in ids) {
  obj[ids[i]] = ""; // This adds a value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[ids[i]]` instead of `ids[i]`.

```js
let ids = [1, 2, 3];

let obj = {};

for (let i in ids) {
  obj = { ...obj, [ids[i]]: "" };
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

`is[i]` is `key` that should be resolve runtime, so you should make it [`computed property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
> supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
> in brackets [], that will be computed and used as the property name.
> This is reminiscent of the bracket notation of the property accessor
> syntax, which you may have used to read and set properties already. - MDN

```js
let ids = [1, 2, 3];

let obj = {};
for (let i in ids) {
  obj = { ...obj, [ids[i]]: "" };
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically set `""` to each `id` as key in the object, I suggest you to do that:

`let obj = {}`
`let ids = [1,2,3]`

```
ids.forEach((id) => {
   obj[id] = '';
});
```

Object will be `{ '1': '', '2': '', '3': ''}`;